# How to resolve can not read only property issue in typescript array object

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, angular8

I am trying to update the array object particular value in angular. But Not able to update the array object values. How to do it in typescript.

`Error: Type Error: Cannot assign to read only property 'createdOn' of object '[object Object]'`

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="updateObject()">Update</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public detailItems: any[] = [
    { id: 1, title: 'user01', createdOn: '2023-08-22T10:15:23.748Z' },
    { id: 2, title: 'user02', createdOn: '2022-08-22T10:15:23.748Z' },
  ];

  updateObject() {
    this.detailItems.filter((a) => {
      a.createdOn = moment(a.createdOn).format('MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf(); //Getting error in this line.
      return a;
    });

    console.log(this.detailItems);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Trying to update the array object values.

Comment: Not the solution for your problem, but you are sort of "misusing* the filter function. If you just want to iterate over the array and do something for every element, use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a simple [`for .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead.